# UICollectionview: Grey Bar on safe Area on scroll to the top

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I hope you are having a great start to your week!

On scrolling up the UICollectionView, a grey bar shows up at the bottom covering the bottom uiView. It goes away when I scroll down. I have looked at multiple posts on stack overflow, I couldn't find one that worked for me. Could you please help?

```
import SwiftUI

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

 @IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
 @IBOutlet var homeButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet var totshelfButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet var profileButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet var tabView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet var buttonStack: UIStackView!
 @IBOutlet var borderView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet var labelView: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        
        myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyReusableView", bundle: .none), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellid)
        
        myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HeaderCollectionReusableView", bundle: .none), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: currMonthID, withReuseIdentifier: headerID)
        
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self
        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        
        let layout = setupLayout()
        myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        myCollectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        myCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        myCollectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(myCollectionView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(borderView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tabView)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(labelView)
        
        self.tabView.layer.zPosition = 1
        self.labelView.layer.zPosition = 1
        self.borderView.layer.zPosition = 1
    
    }

    func setupLayout()-> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout{
    
       return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionNumber, env in 
       
                     let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1)))
                               item.contentInsets.trailing = 12
                               item.contentInsets.bottom = 20
                               
                           let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(0.5)), subitems: [item])
                               let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 80, trailing: 0)
                           
                           section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [.init(layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(50.0)), elementKind: self.currMonthID, alignment: .topLeading)]
                           
                           return section

       }
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: self.myCollectionView.frame.width, height: self.myCollectionView.frame.height)
    
    }


}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS2D3.jpg)
[View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBNEh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to play with the zpositions. From your question, I could not find out why you use that tabView. You should try to embed the view to a tabbarcontroller.

But try to send "back" the tabview or move forward everything else. And I feel it is not a final solution, but definitely can be a fix.

```
self.tabView.layer.zPosition = 0
```

or

```
myCollectionView.layer.zPosition = 3
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick and kind response, Akos! I tried this and unfortunately it hasn't worked. Please do let me know what else I could try.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want a custom tabbar? And you just constraint there a UIView? You can customise a tab bar to look as you want. It will make your life much easier. I guess you embed your Viewcontroller to a TabbarController. If you select your Viewcontroller on the storyboard and go on the menubar: Editor->Embed In->Tab bar controller. If it is ticked, just untick it and the tab bar will go away. But if you want a tab bar controlled application you should use a tab bar controller, and customise the way it looks.

Comment: Hi Akos, yes, I am attempting a custom tab bar. I will try what you recommended. Could you please let me know what causes that grey bar at the bottom on scrolling the UICollectionView?

Comment: That grey bar at the bottom is the System tabbar, that what Tabbar controller uses. As I mentioned the previous comment, you have to create a custom class for the tabbar and connect with the tabbar on the storyboard. And you can modify the looks. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N4lxebmJ2U

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, Akos! :) Apologies, my vote for your response isn't reflected since I am pretty new to StackOverflow.